# RewriteRule not working for multi URL

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[a-zA-Z0-9-+/]{3,}\ /+company\.php\?title=([^\s&]+)
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[a-zA-Z0-9-+/]{3,}\ /+project\.php\?compname=([^\s&]+)&prjt=([^\s&]+)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ company.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ project.php [L]
```

what I expect is http://website.com/compname=Company&prjt=Project  should look like http://website.com/Company/Project. And the same way company.php page also. Company.php page s working as expected, But project.php page is not working. Url is showing as expected, But page opening with complete errors. Any help is highly thankful?

Comment: What are the errors? Put the errors in the question that you're getting

Comment: Hi, Thanks again. Your code is working for Company page only. For project page http://www.website.co/company/project/ is coming in address bar. Company page is coming here without style sheet (messy look). We need project page here. If a chat option is here I can shw you website. @PanamaJack

Answer (score 0):

If you're missing styles and scripts, your problem is most likely that you're using relative links in your content. When you change the URL from

```
/project.php
```

to

```
 /company/project
```

any relative URL's will have the base change from `/` to `/company/`, which is obviously not what you want.

Either make all your links absolute URLs that start with a `/` or add a base to your page headers:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> Company page is coming here without style sheet (messy look).

That's what I was asking you. We need to know the specific problem because opening with errors is not the same as your style sheet is missing.

Fix your stylesheet problem by adding this tag in your `<head>` section.

```
<base href="http://www.website.co" />
```

This happens when using this type of mod_rewrite and relative URL's in your html for CSS/JS etc.